# JSON data enum types

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JSON object like this.

```
var data={
"Company" : "XYZ",
"company" : ['RX','TX']
}
```

The above json data has 2 keys Company whose type is string and company whose type is **enum but not array**(I didnt know how to represent enum in json data),because of which json schema says its an array. I want it to be enum type.

**So how will I represent Enum type in JSON data?**

Comment: An enum in any language represents a set of possible values but in an object it only takes 1 value. In JSON is the same, you can define a set of values in a JSON Schema, but then in JSON data it takes only one of those values.

Answer (score 12):

JSON has no `enum` type. The two ways of modeling an `enum` would be:

**An array**, as you have currently. The array values are the elements, and the element identifiers would be represented by the array indexes of the values. This, however, does not model sparse enums (enums where the first index is not zero OR where the identifiers are not sequential).

```
enum suit {
  clubs = 0,
  diamonds,
  hearts,
  spades,
};

// is equivalent to

"suitEnum": ["clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"];
```

**A map**, which is less compact but solves the array limitations:

```
enum suit {
  clubs = 10,
  diamonds = 20,
  hearts = 30,
  spades = 40,
};

// is equivalent to

"suitEnum": {
  "clubs": 10,
  "diamonds": 20,
  "hearts": 30,
  "spades": 40
};
```