# FromQueryAttribute enum parameters throw validation_error invalid value, but parameters with FromBodyAttribute do not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, enums, model-binding

In ASP.NET Core, if an action accepts directly an enum type, and that enum for example has defined `1` to something, if we pass a value different than 1, we'll get a validation error.

This is good! But it doesn't work for when the enum is inside a complex object type, when they are built from the body of a request (`[FromBody]` attribute).

Why is this happening? I know that anything coming from the body, is being handled by JSON Converters. Why can't they handle this for us, when the Query binder (what/where is it?) does it for us?

Example Enum:

```
public Enum Example
{
   One = 1
}
```

Example Action:

```
public object ExampleAction(Enum hello)
{
   return Ok();
}
```

If you hit the action with a HTTP request, passing in the `hello` parameter in a query string with a value different than 1, you will get a validation error.

Now, if you annotate the `hello` parameter with the `[FromBody]` attribute and make a new request (passing in this time the data via the body instead of the query string), that behavior is lost.

Comment: @Yinqiu what difference does it make? How are they able to be successfully bound and validated via the query, but not via the body?

Comment: This seems to be caused by the default behavior in json conversion, unable to pass enum type json

Comment: For more information about json, you can check the official json document.

Comment: @Yinqiu could you toss in a link please? Are you referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.1)? Because it doesn't say anything useful other than the methods it provides.

Comment: You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052750/json-data-enum-types) thread,may be it helpful to you .

Comment: Hi @SpiritBob,you can see this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42093),it solved your question.